# C pointer casting - weird results

Tags: c, pointers, memory, casting

Consider this short code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    short s[] = {0xAB, 0xCD};
    
    printf("%x\n", *(char*)s);
    printf("%x\n", *((char*)s+1));
}
```

I thought casting s to char* would allow me to step bytewise through the array, producing the output

```
a
b
```

But instead I get this:

```
ffffffab
0
```

Can someone explain this to me? I'm running gcc 4.8.1 on x64.

Comment: `char`, in your implementation, is **signed**.

Comment: type mismatch in `printf("%x\n", *(char*)s);` ... `"%x"` assumes a value of `unsigned` type, you are *sending* a `int` value which was automatically converted from `char`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What happens in your program

The output aligns with the following assumptions about your system (which are typical for a wide range of x86 based systems):

- `short int`s are 16 bits (i.e., 2 bytes) wide.
- Regular `int`s are 32 bits (i.e., 4 bytes) wide.
- `char` is a signed type.
- The CPU endianness is "little endian [first]", that is, an integer of the value `0x01020304` is stored in memory as `04 03 02 01`.

Let's go step by step.

> short s[] = {0xAB, 0xCD};

This creates an array of 2-byte shorts. Arrays by definition don't have gaps between the elements, so the resulting memory in ascending address order starting at `s` is

```
_____________________
| ab | 00 | cd | 00 |
|  s[0]   |  s[1]   |
_____________________
|         s         |
_____________________
  ^
Byte pointed to by (char *)s
```

Now comes a bit of a technicality: `printf` is a variadic function, that is, its argument types past the first one (always a `const char *`) are unknown at compile time (compile time of `printf`!). Numeric arguments of variadic function calls undergo a "default argument promotion" by the compiler (that was specified probably in order to make dealing with the arguments easier for the function implementation). One of the promotions is the "integer promotion": All integer values smaller than `int` are promoted to `int`. That is, **the code of the `printf` implementation in the library never sees `short` or `char` arguments;** it *does* interpret the `int`s it sees though according to the format string, and for example does not output the character sequence "65" but "A" when it encounters an `int` argument with the value 65 that corresponds to a `char` conversion in the format string.

Therefore, when you call `printf("%x\n", *(char*)s)` against all appearances **you are passing an `int` argument to `printf`.** The sequence of events is:

1. Adjust `s` from a `short[2]` to a `short *` (arrays undergo this adjustment or "decay" in most expressions). The pointer points to the first element.
2. Cast the `short *` pointer to a `char *`. It still points to the same address, the "first byte" (i.e., the byte at the lowest address) in the short.
3. Dereference the char pointer. The result is the `char` at the lowest address in the first element of `s`, which is `'\ab'`. Because your `char` type is signed, this value is -85. That may be unexpected because we typically think of characters as typographical entities like 'A' or '0'; but in C they are just a very short integer type which holds a — potentially signed — number.
4. Pass the `char`with the value -85 to printf. As discussed the `char` with the value -85 will be promoted to int, without changing its value. The byte representation for a 4 byte `int` -85 on a little endian system with 2-complement is `ab ff ff ff`. This is what is passed to `printf` by some variadic argument magic.
5. With "%x", you instruct `printf` to interpret the received value as an `unsigned int` (!). That is technically not correct — it is undefined behavior — because the actual argument was a *signed* `int`. (Of course, all implementations known to mankind simply interpret the bytes differently with no ill side-effects.) The byte sequence `ab ff ff ff`, interpreted as an `unsigned int` on a little endian system with 4 byte `int`s, is the value ‭4,294,967,211, that is `0xffffffab`. This is what your first `printf` outputs.

The second one works very much the same, except that you print the second byte in the array. Above we saw that the byte sequence in memory of the array is `ab | 00 | cd | 00`; `s` points to the `ab` byte; the next byte has the value 0 which undergoes all the hubbub detailed above, none of which changes its value, until 0 is printed.

#### How to get your desired output

The "a" and "b" in a byte like "0xab" each show the value of 4 bits *within* a single byte. They are hexadecimal digits. Hex digits consist of our common Arabic digits 0..9 plus the first 6 letters of the Latin alphabet (and are commonly used in California, a shining example of how only a common effort of diverse cultures, across continents and millenia, enabled mankind to hate each other on Twitter). They stand for the numeric values 0..15, 15 being displayed as "F" or "f". A 4-bit-number can have 16 different values, each of which corresponds to one of the digits. A byte with its 8 bits is composed of two of these sub-values, which are called *nibbles.* Therefore we can depict any byte value with just two characters. "0x00" means no bit is set while "0xff" means all bits are set.  Note that nibbles, let alone bits are not separately addressable — we can only obtain entire bytes and have to extract the bits from them "manually" using operators like the binary AND `&` or the bit shift operator `>>`. We'll do both below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    short s[] = {0xAB, 0xCD};
    unsigned char *byteArr = (unsigned char *)s;
    // Iterate through s, bytewise
    for(int byteIndex=0; byteIndex < sizeof(s); byteIndex++)
    {
        // For each byte, print both nibbles, 
        // most significant one first.
        unsigned int byteVal = byteArr[byteIndex];
        unsigned int hiNibble = (byteVal & 0xf0) >> 4;
        unsigned int loNibble = (byteVal & 0xf);
        printf("Hi/lo nibble of byte no. %d, %2x (%3u): %x, %x\n",
                byteIndex, byteVal, byteVal, 
                hiNibble, loNibble);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hi/lo nibble of byte no. 0, ab (171): a, b
Hi/lo nibble of byte no. 1,  0 (  0): 0, 0
Hi/lo nibble of byte no. 2, cd (205): c, d
Hi/lo nibble of byte no. 3,  0 (  0): 0, 0
```

Comment: ***`The CPU endianness is "little endian [first]`*** What are ***`CPU endianness is "little endian [last]`***

Comment: @0___________ *little endian [last]* would be *big endian [first]* ;-). No, seriously: I could never memorize which is which until I learned the meaning (which byte is first) which is why I included the mnemonics in square brackets.

Answer (score 4):

Use the correct printf format if you want one byte.

```
short s[] = {0xAB, 0xCD};

printf("%hhx\n", *(unsigned char*)s);
printf("%hhx\n", *((unsigned char*)s+1));
printf("%hhx\n", *((unsigned char*)s+2));
printf("%hhx\n", *((unsigned char*)s+3));
```

Then you will see the correct output `ab 0 cd 0`. It will also indicate that your system is little endian. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

[image]

Comment: The answer is wrong, I am not getting `cd` anywhere in my stdout

Comment: @MukulKumar this answer **is correct**. `I am not getting cd anywhere in my stdout` means that **you** are doing something wrong https://godbolt.org/z/ndobqa

Comment: Yeah, I checked and it was an error on my part, sorry

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know the `h`or `hh` length modifiers. I probably always cast the argument to int instead.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I have added the table with some more.

Comment: Second thought: To be honest, what purpose do the "hh" length modifiers serve? The `unsigned char` argument is promoted to `int` anyway, and the result cannot have any value outside the `unsigned char` range. If you check your example in godbolt the output does not change when you omit "hh". (**Ah:** It *is* useful for signed values, but only for hex output.)